# How To Get Data Back From Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i hope somebody could help me with a small example, because angular is driving me crazy :(

I'm making by first time a Formular that should follow this structure:
Angular APP

mainController
---->smallController1
-------->otherElements
---->smallController2
-------->otherElements
---->**Directive1 (instance 1)**
---->anotherSmallController
---->**Directive1 (instance 2)**

The Directive1 receives many attributes, and each instance will allow the selection of many options, and the result of the user interaction should be stored in an object, and that object should be accessed from mainController for each instance separately.

Does anyone have an example that work like that?

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: That's a pretty vague question, can you be more specific? You want to access the data in Directive1 from mainController? There are so many ways you can do that in different situations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to get data back from directive is to attach a model to directive's self scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', 
                [
  '$scope', 
  function($scope){
    $scope.myObj = "Initial Value";
  }
]);

app.directive('dirName', [
  function(){
    return {
      restrict : 'A',
      scope : {
        obj : "=ngModel"
      },
      link : function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.obj = attrs.newValue;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
  <input dir-name ng-model="myObj" new-value="Final Value">
</body>
</html>
```

You can check this bin as well : http://jsbin.com/fuqujo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Use emit to send data to parent controller. 
It may be receiver because listening to event. 
[Read](https://sathyalog.wordpress.com/tag/difference-between-broadcast-and-emit/) about on emit and broadcast. 
In your child controller or directive use:

$scope.$emit('myEvent', object);

This sends object to all parent controllers. 
In parent controller use:

$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, obj) { console.log(obj); });

To listen to emitted object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out, it might help you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/L1NwUnNePofyRAQ6GVIg?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.masterData = [
    {
      entry: 'dunno'
    },
    {
      entry: 'stuff'
    }
  ]
})
app.directive('vessel', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      speciality: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.updateData = function() {
        scope.data.entry = scope.speciality;
      }
    },
    template: '<div>{{data.entry}} <button ng-click="updateData()">update</button></div>'
  }
});
```

And the template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Master data {{masterData | json}}</p>
    <div vessel data="masterData[0]" speciality="eggs"></div>
    <div vessel data="masterData[1]" speciality="bacon"></div>
  </body>
```

So, we have separate data models for each directive which are updated on user input, fitting your requirements. Right?